# Access Denied error when running kompose up

Tags: docker, kompose

I installed `kompose` using brew.

When I run `kompose up` I get

```
ERRO Unable to push image 'tolicodes/tolicodes.com:latest' to registry 'docker.io'. Error: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required
```

my `~/.docker/config.json` looks like:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
    },
    "HttpHeaders": {
        "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.8 (darwin)"
    },
    "credsStore": "desktop",
    "experimental": "disabled",
    "stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
}
```

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  frontend-dev:
    build:
      context: .
      target: dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    stdin_open: true
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      target: prod
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    image: tolicodes/tolicodes.com
```

I've successfully run `docker login`

Comment: What's in your `docker-compose.yml` file?  Have you successfully `docker login`?

Comment: yep. and updated to include my compsoe

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the base64 encoded username/password to the config

```
echo -n 'username:password'  | base64
```

In `~/.docker/config.json`

```
"auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
      "auth": "<THE OUTPUT>"
    }
  },
```